# run aws polly with shell variables

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I want to execute the following line of code in a shellscript:

```bsh
for i in $(seq $num $END);
do aws polly synthesize-speech --text-type text --text "$(cat $stored.cp.$i.txt)" --output-format mp3 --voice-id Joanna $stored.$i.mp3
done
```

This is supposed to generate `mp3` files based from text. `aws` is installed correctly, but the script doesnt work. I run the `.sh` file via a `php` script.

Is it possible that a shell programm doesn't accept shell parameter as `$stored` or the counter `$i`?

Edit: I now think it can be solved with $PATH variable, however when I include the path of aws it shows permission denied.   I dont know how to include it correctly so that the aws-cli reads the credentials and config file.

its super important to me.

https://serverfault.com/questions/614890/cant-run-aws-cli-from-cron-credentials this helps but I still dont get it

Thanks a lot

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question ([edit]). (see [How do I ask a good question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: For debugging, change `aws...` to `echo aws...`

Comment: I wanted to create text to speech mp3s for a sequence of files with amazons polly text to speech engine.  Nothing happend no mp3-file generated